# Creating text file containing unique words from an input text file

Tags: python, parsing

I have written a code to create a text file containing all the unique words from another text file. However I am not getting any output. though the code is running without error.

Input text file , g.txt :

*I am not a robot
I am a human
I am a girl
I am not a woman
I am a school girl
I go to high school*

The text file can have blank lines or spaces.

My code is as follows :

```
def unique_file(input_filename, output_filename):
    input_file = open('g.txt', 'r')
    file_contents = input_file.read()
    word_list = file_contents.split()
    
   

    file = open('n.txt', 'w')

    unique_words = set(word_list)
    for word in unique_words:
        file.write(str(word) + "\n")
    file.close()
```

The program is not creating the output file n.txt.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call the function:

```
def unique_file(input_filename, output_filename):
    with open(input_filename) as input_file:
        file_contents = input_file.read()
        word_list = file_contents.split()

    file = open(output_filename, 'w')

    unique_words = set(word_list)
    for word in unique_words:
        file.write(str(word) + "\n")
    file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unique_file('g.txt', 'n.txt')
```

Here's a more optimized version of your code:

```
def unique_file(input_filename, output_filename):
    with open(input_filename) as infile, open(output_filename, 'w') as outfile:
        file_contents = infile.read()
        word_list = file_contents.split()

        unique_words = set(word_list)
        for word in unique_words:
            outfile.write(str(word) + "\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unique_file('g.txt', 'n.txt')
```